# Regex string for Sublime Text to find email address between two commas

Tags: ruby, regex, csv, sublimetext2

I'm new to regex's and Sublime's and am having issues trying to do a find/replace on all email addresses in a csv file.

I thought it would be reasonably straightforward but seem to be heading down the rabbit hole at a great rate of knots.

Data looks like;

data,data,email@address.com,data,data etc NB: there are about 100 fields per record and about 300 records

My thought was to look for the @ symbol, then go left and right until I get to the comma and then replace with my new email address but I just can't get a win.

Any thoughts or am I using the wrong tool for the job?

(Also tagging with Ruby as if I need to do some scripting then I'll try to get figure it out in Ruby)

Thanks,
Liam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the ruby language, but a regex that finds what you want is:

```
\w+\@\w+\.\w+
```

with the \. maybe unneeded (depending on language).

a perl one-liner that does the exact thing:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\w+\@\w+\.\w+/<your new email here>/g' <csv file here>
```

**note**

make sure you use \@ in the enw email in the one liner i wrote, meaning `new_email\@server.com`

Comment: Perfect - if I plunk that into Sublime's 'Find' field it matches all the right fields - Thank you!!

Comment: I modified the above mentioned regex as `\S+\@\w+\.\w+` to capture in case a period or other special character is used in the username portion of the email address.  `w` would only capture alphanumeric characters.

Comment: This fails to recognize domains with more than one do like @domain.com.ar

Answer (score 3):

user2141046's expression won't find an email address like- "a.b@c.com"

I would suggest using:

> [a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*

[Source](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10408)

Comment: This fails to recognize domains with more than one do like @domain.com.ar

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*
```

It worked perfectly on a very long csv file filled with emails and all other kinds of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```

will not work fine, because some domains have 2 or more levels (like com.br)
Use:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[\.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```